# clearing wordpress nulled theme from malicious code before uploading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to find the malicious code in wordpress nulled theme . Can that be possible before uploading the theme to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the theme in a sandboxed WordPress environment and test the theme with exploit scanner: https://wordpress.org/plugins/exploit-scanner/